# Repeating Audio in WatchKit (AVAudioPlayer?)?

Tags: watchkit, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I am wanting to loop a local audio file in my Apple Watch App. Currently I am using AVAudioPlayerNode and AVAudioEngine which works well but I cannot figure out how to loop the sound.

I noticed that I can use AVAudioPlayer, which has the handy "numberOfLoops" but, for some reason AVAudioPlayer is not working on the watch. I have no idea why.

Here is my current code to play a sound:

```
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
_audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
[_audioEngine attachNode:_audioPlayer];

AVAudioFormat *stereoFormat = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initStandardFormatWithSampleRate:44100 channels:2];
[_audioEngine connect:_audioPlayer to:_audioEngine.mainMixerNode format:stereoFormat];

if (!_audioEngine.isRunning) {
    NSError* error;
    [_audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error];
}

NSError *error;
NSBundle* appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[appBundle pathForResource:@"FILE_NAME" ofType:@"mp3"]];
AVAudioFile *asset = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:url error:&error];

[_audioPlayer scheduleFile:asset atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
[_audioPlayer play];
```

Here is the code i've tried to use for AVAudioPlayer, but does not work:

```
NSError *audioError;
AVAudioPlayer* player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FILE_NAME" ofType:@"mp3"]] error:&audioError];
player.numberOfLoops = MAXFLOAT;
player.delegate = self;
[player play];
```

I am using WatchKit 5.0(+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your audio file fits into memory, you could schedule playback as an `AVAudioBuffer` with the `AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops` option (**N.B.** only tested on simulator!):

```
AVAudioFormat *outputFormat = [_audioPlayer outputFormatForBus:0];

__block AVAudioPCMBuffer *srcBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:asset.processingFormat frameCapacity:(AVAudioFrameCount)asset.length];

if (![asset readIntoBuffer:srcBuffer error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Read error: %@", error);
    abort();
}

AVAudioPCMBuffer *dstBuffer = [[AVAudioPCMBuffer alloc] initWithPCMFormat:outputFormat frameCapacity:(AVAudioFrameCount)asset.length];

AVAudioConverter *converter = [[AVAudioConverter alloc] initFromFormat:srcBuffer.format toFormat:dstBuffer.format];
AVAudioConverterOutputStatus status = [converter convertToBuffer:dstBuffer error:&error withInputFromBlock:^AVAudioBuffer * _Nullable(AVAudioPacketCount inNumberOfPackets, AVAudioConverterInputStatus * _Nonnull outStatus) {
    if (srcBuffer) {
        AVAudioBuffer *result = srcBuffer;
        srcBuffer = NULL;
        *outStatus = AVAudioConverterInputStatus_HaveData;
        return result;
    } else {
        *outStatus = AVAudioConverterInputStatus_EndOfStream;
        return NULL;
    }
}];

assert(status != AVAudioConverterOutputStatus_Error);

[_audioPlayer scheduleBuffer:dstBuffer atTime:nil options:AVAudioPlayerNodeBufferLoops completionHandler:nil];
[_audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop your `AVAudioFile` by recursively scheduling it:

```
__block __weak void (^weakSheduleFile)(void);
void (^scheduleFile)(void);

weakSheduleFile = scheduleFile = ^{ [self->_audioPlayer scheduleFile:asset atTime:nil completionHandler:weakSheduleFile]; };

scheduleFile();
```

I'm not sure if this will be a seamless loop. If it's not, you can try always having two files scheduled:

```
scheduleFile();
scheduleFile();
```

Comment: Endless loop works perfect using your code, but I would like to request "play again" after every loop with UIAlertController - could not get this to work, any idea / recommendation?

Comment: Can you phrase this as a new question with some code?

Comment: Ok here is the new question with code ... hope you can help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044213/repeating-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer